# Find substring or exact string in php

Tags: php

When I use strpos it returns false if the both strings are equal. Is there a function or a parameter to this function that returns tru if there is a substring in the main string or both strings are equal?

Or am i wrong and it does it for the full string also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong - `strpos()` does not return `false`, it returns `0`. Just do `strpos() !== false` to find out if it matched.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't returning false, you're just not checking strict equality. Use `===` instead of `==`, cause it found it at index 0.